# Making QDialog Transparent in Qt by keeping its child widget(s) opacity Normal

Tags: c++, qt, transparency, opacity, qdialog

I need to make a `QDialog` transparent with its child widgets(widgets contained in the QDialog) having opacity 1. That is I need the transparency applied only to the `QDialog` and not to its child widgets as well.

I use the following method to set the opacity of my dialog

```
QGraphicsOpacityEffect* opacityEffect = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect;
myDialog->setGraphicsEffect(opacityEffect);
opacityEffect->setOpacity(0.45); // I need to set it to this particular value
```

But this also sets the opacity of child wdigets of myDialog to 0.45, means making them too transparent. Is there any way to restrict the `Opacityeffect` to `myDialog` only? Thus making its child widgets look normal.

Comment: I think you can check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30882098) which helped me a lot at least.